Android: VpnService cutting off network access when VPN is on
I have extended VpnService and trying to route all the traffic through it. I am able to connect to vpn successfully as I can see it in the status bar. But when I do so, I am not able to access anything over network. I have checked the sample repos available and I am doing all minimal things that I required to achieve this but it's still not working for me.
The output for ip route looks like following when vpn is connected.
adb shell ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2

Sharing the code for vpn builder configuration.
 private fun startVpn() {
        val builder = Builder()

        builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32)
            .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0) // Route all IPv4 traffic through the VPN
            .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
            .addDnsServer("8.8.4.4")
        
        

        try {
            vpnInterface = builder.establish()
            Timber.d("$LOG_PREFIX: VPN Interface established")
           

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Timber.d("$LOG_PREFIX: Failed to establish VPN interface: ${e.message}")
            stopSelf()
        }
    }
    ```
Please help on how to debug this further or fix this.

